# OAuth2 server to server communication between two RESTful web apis in .NET Core

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I know how to implement token based security via OAUTH to protect the access of an api. I also know ho to use HTTPClient to call an api.

But when I search/google how to use OAUTH calling a web api from a web api all it shows me is how to implement token based security for an web api (which I already have).

In my scenario I have an UI calling web api 1. After that I have to do some server to server communication: web api 1 calls web api 2 and web api 2 calls web api 3. Web Api 3 does something & returns to web api 2 which then does something based on success or failure, then returns to web api 1 (which does something) returning back to the UI.
(The reason for that intended implementation is storing (different) data in 3 different databases where I currently do not want (and later maybe not be allowed to) grant web api 1 direct access to them.

I am just unclear how I would manage the tokens (I don't want to request them every time, so I guess I will need some kind of service handling that and keeping them).

Any hint I could get the authorization (token handling) done?

Comment: which authorisation service are you planning to use? Some have clients / SDKs to help with getting / caching tokens. e.g. AAD has ADAL.

Comment: @iandayman I am using an implementation based on Identity Server 4.